# Hibernate collection removal after flush

Tags: hibernate, collections

The collection data is removed from the database after a session flush. It seems [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29) detected the original collection is replaced, but in our legacy project, we don't want Hibernate to do the removal. Is there any way to do it?

Below is the sample code:

```
public class Student{
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="student_id")
    private List<Course> courses;
    ......

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Student s = (Student) session.get(Student.class, id);
        //set new name
        s.setName("new name");

        // this is neccessary in our project, and I can't change it.
        List<Course> newCourses = new ArrayList<Course>();
        newCourses.add(...);
        s.setCourses(newCourses);  // replace the collection with new

        //update s
        session.update(s);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

After a transaction commit, Hibernate will remove the collection data in the database, because the original collection is replaced with a new one, but I don't want Hibernate to do this. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: are you not showing some cascade mappings?

Comment: no cascade for the collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you only want to add some courses for a student. So you should only add the new courses to the student's exisitng `courses` list instead of replacing it with a new list:

```
List newCourses = new ArrayList();
newCourses.add(...);

/*** Add a list of new course instead of replacing with a new list***/
s.addCourse(newCourses);
```

`addCourse(List courseList)` is a method of the Student which will add all elements of the input list `courseList` to the student's internal `courses` list.

Comment: since it is a legacy system, it used OJB before, and there are many places like:  s.setCourses(newCourses); in the system. Now I am doing the migration from OJB to Hibernate, i don't want to change all these places, since it a big work.

Comment: To be honest , I don't think hibernate has such setting in the mapping or configuration xml because it violates the design principle of hibernate , which first keep track the state of the entities in the memory and delay issuing the SQL to the DB  as late as possible until the flushing process . If you really remove the collection from the item , it will be removed from the DB finally. So , i don't think you can get your desired result without modifying any codes .